# Cannot insert data with stord procedure. (0 row(s) affected) There is some error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_BOOKEDVEHICLES
 @flag bit output,-- return 0 for fail,1 for success
 @REGISTRATIONID varchar(30),
 @VEHICLEID varchar(9),
 @VEHICLENAME varchar(20)
 AS
 BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION 
  BEGIN TRY 
 Insert into BST_TVL_BOOKED_VEHICLES_TB(REGISTRATIONID, VEHICLEID, VEHICLENAME) Values(@REGISTRATIONID,@VEHICLEID,@VEHICLENAME)
  set @flag=1;
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN commit TRANSACTION;
  END
  END TRY 
 BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN rollback TRANSACTION;
  END
  set @flag=0;
  END CATCH
END
GO

Declare @flag bit
 EXEC sp_BOOKEDVEHICLES @flag output, 
 @REGISTRATIONID = '2364', 
 @VEHICLEID = '27',
 @VEHICLENAME = 'Ford'

 if @flag=1
  print 'Successfully inserted'
 else
  print 'There is some error'
```

Obviously, there is an error in the code, but i can't find it... Cannot insert data with stord procedure.
It shows me this error : (0 row(s) affected) There is some error.

Comment: It working in my side. I don't see any error

Comment: Delete all this code and leave just the insert. Handle the error in the app. This is trivial to do there. Use `TransactionScope`.

Comment: Did you try the re-written stored procedure?  If you are calling from a C# or other program, just remove the SELECT in the catch so that you do not have to deal with a return record set.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into BST_TVL_BOOKED_VEHICLES_TB(REGISTRATIONID, VEHICLEID, VEHICLENAME) Values(@REGISTRATIONID,@VEHICLEID,@VEHICLENAME)
  set @flag=1;
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN commit TRANSACTION;
  END
```

This must throw an SQL Exception, because `@flag <> 1`. Try `print ERROR_MESSAGE()` in order to get description of the actual error ?

Comment: Nothing happens :( I have the same procedure for the other tables but give me an error only in this one ..

Comment: What is the result of this query "Insert into BST_TVL_BOOKED_VEHICLES_TB(REGISTRATIONID, VEHICLEID, VEHICLENAME) Values(@REGISTRATIONID,@VEHICLEID,@VEHICLENAME)" ?

Comment: It said that it is successfully created. The problem comes in Declare part I think.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you are mixing up some concepts.

1 - Transactions are used when you want multiple statements to either commit or roll back.

For instance, debit from customer account and credit vendor.  Either both commit or rollback.

2 - Since you do not have that condition, just wrap the insert with a TRY/CATCH.

See my blog on ways to error handle.

http://craftydba.com/?tag=error-handling

3 - Procedures can return a value.  Why not zero if good and one if bad.

I rewrote your code as below.

```
--
--  Re-write of code
-- 

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_BOOKEDVEHICLES
   @REGISTRATIONID varchar(30),
   @VEHICLEID varchar(9),
   @VEHICLENAME varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
  -- TRY TO ADD A RECORD
  BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO BST_TVL_BOOKED_VEHICLES_TB 
      (REGISTRATIONID, VEHICLEID, VEHICLENAME) 
    VALUES 
      (@REGISTRATIONID, @VEHICLEID, @VEHICLENAME);
    RETURN 0;
  END TRY 

 -- CATCH ERROR
 BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
       ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
       ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
       ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
       ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
   RETURN 1;
 END CATCH
END
GO

-- Sample call
DECLARE @RETCODE INT
 EXEC @RETCODE = sp_BOOKEDVEHICLES 
   @REGISTRATIONID = '2364', 
   @VEHICLEID = '27',
   @VEHICLENAME = 'Ford';

-- Just show the result.
IF @RETCODE = 1 
  PRINT 'BAD INSERT CALL'
ELSE
  PRINT 'GOOD INSERT CALL';
```

Please test the code since I do not have your table defined ...